# 2sxc Designers in 9.4.2 Not Working for Me

Tags: 2sxc

I am running into an issue where I can't get the "2sxc Designers" role to work properly in 2sxc 9.4.2 and DNN 9.1.1.

1. I created the "2sxc Designers" role. As a result the advanced buttons are hidden from everyone but Superusers.  That is good.
2. I put one of my editor accounts into the role "2sxc Designers" but the account still cannot see the advanced buttons.
3. I've tried "Restart Application" and "Clear Cache".  What am I missing?

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Basically your description is correct, it should work. If it doesn't, I'm guessing some minor thing isn't configured correctly. Could you check it a bit more to be sure you did it right, because as of now nobody else has reported this. If you can drill it down to really be an issue / bug, then post in on github.